# HTTP code 403: Forbidden from Microsoft visual studio team foundation service 2012 cloud service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I have my project hosted in Microsoft visual studio team foundation service(2012) cloud services. But when my team mates try to get latest version from this project, they get 
**"HTTP code 403: Forbidden"**
 errors randomly on few files. what could be the root cause for these errors. But looks like they have read/checkin/checkout access for all the files under the project.

Comment: Tell me more about your corporate proxy...?

Comment: @Edwardthomson thanks for that direction. yeah, i guess its my corporate proxy which blocks the files being downloaded from the cloud. because i had not got downloaded even a single file from the cloud except folders. Final point is that we used to get this same error when we try to install nuget packages from microsoft nuget repository using nuget package manager.